# JMS queue is full

Tags: java, jboss, jms

My Java EE application sends JMS to queue continuously, but sometimes the JMS consumer application stopped receiving JMS. It causes the JMS queue very large even full, that collapses the server.
My server is JBoss or Websphere. Do the application servers provide strategy to remove "timeout" JMS messages?

What is strategy to handle large JMS queue? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With any asynchronous messaging you must deal with the "fast producer/slow consumer" problem.  There are a number of ways to deal with this.

1. Add consumers.  With WebSphere MQ you can trigger a queue based on depth.  Some shops use this to add new consumer instances as queue depth grows.  Then as queue depth begins to decline, the extra consumers die off.  In this way, consumers can be made to automatically scale to accommodate changing loads.  Other brokers generally have similar functionality.
2. Make the queue and underlying file system really large.  This method attempts to absorb peaks in workload entirely in the queue.  This is after all what queuing was designed to do in the first place.  Problem is, it doesn't scale well and you must allocate disk that 99% of the time will be almost empty.
3. Expire old messages.  If the messages have an expiry set then you can cause them to be cleaned up.  Some JMS brokers will do this automatically while on others you may need to browse the queue in order to cause the expired messages to be deleted.  Problem with this is that not all messages lose their business value and become eligible for expiry. Most fire-and-forget messages (audit logs, etc.) fall into this category.
4. Throttle back the producer.  When the queue fills, nothing can put new messages to it.  In WebSphere MQ the producing application then receives a return code indicating that the queue is full.  If the application distinguishes between fatal and transient errors, it can stop and retry.

The key to successfully implementing any of these is that your system be allowed to provide "soft" errors that the application will respond to.  For example, many shops will raise the MAXDEPTH parameter of a queue the first time they get a QFULL condition.  If the queue depth exceeds the size of the underlying file system the result is that instead of a "soft" error that impacts a single queue the file system fills and the entire node is affected.  You are MUCH better off tuning the system so that the queue hits MAXDEPTH well before the file system fills but then also instrumenting the app or other processes to react to the full queue in some way.

But no matter what else you do, option #4 above is mandatory.  No matter how much disk you allocate or how many consumer instances you deploy or how quickly you expire messages there is always a possibility that your consumer(s) won't keep up with message production.  When this happens your producer app should throttle back, or raise an alarm and stop or do anything other than hang or die.  Asynchronous messaging is only asynchronous up to the point that you run out of space to queue messages.  After that your apps are synchronous and must gracefully handle that situation, even if that means to (gracefully) shut own.

Comment: Thank you T.Rob! Your answer is comprehensive and beautiful!

Comment: Glad to have been of some help!

Answer (score 3):

Sure!

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jms/javadoc-102a/index.html
`Message#setJMSExpiration(long)` does exactly what you want.